# How to write sophisticated subquery as from clause in ecto?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to write in Ecto syntax following sql query, how to write subquery after `FROM hierarchy,` line, it's in from clause, but I doubt if it is possible in Ecto? I wonder if I can perform such query with use of table joins or even lateral joins without performance loss with the same effect?

```
SELECT routes.id, routes.name
FROM routes
WHERE routes.id IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT hierarchy.parent
   FROM hierarchy,
    (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(segments.rels) AS rel
     FROM segments
     WHERE ST_Intersects(segments.geom, ST_SetSrid(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1866349.262143 6886808.978425)', -1), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1883318.282423 6876413.542579)', -1)), 3857))) AS anon_1
   WHERE hierarchy.child = anon_1.rel)
```

I've stuck on following code:

```
hierarchy_subquery =
  Hierarchy
  |> distinct([h], h.parent)
Route
|> select([r], r.id, r.name)
|> where([r], r.id in subquery(hierarchy_subquery))
```

Schemas:

```
defmodule MyApp.Hierarchy do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "hierarchy" do
    field :parent, :integer
    field :child, :integer
    field :deph, :integer
  end
end
defmodule MyApp.Route do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "routes" do
    field :name, :string
    field :intnames, :map
    field :symbol, :string
    field :country, :string
    field :network, :string
    field :level, :integer
    field :top, :boolean
    field :geom, Geo.Geometry, srid: 3857
  end
end
defmodule MyApp.Segment do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "segments" do
    field :ways, {:array, :integer}
    field :nodes, {:array, :integer}
    field :rels, {:array, :integer}
    field :geom, Geo.LineString, srid: 3857
  end
end
```

**EDIT** I've tested performance of various queries and this below is fastest:

```
from r in Route,
        join: h in Hierarchy, on: r.id == h.parent,
        join: s in subquery(
          from s in Segment,
            distinct: true,
            where: fragment("ST_Intersects(?, ST_SetSrid(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1285982.015631 7217169.814674)', -1), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2371999.313507 6454022.524275)', -1)), 3857))", s.geom),
            select: %{rel: fragment("unnest(?)", s.rels)}
        ),
        where: s.rel == h.child,
        select: {r.id, r.name}
```

Results:

> Planning time: ~0.605 ms Execution time: ~37.232 ms

The same query as above but `join` replaced by `inner_lateral_join` for segments subquery:

> Planning time: ~1.353 ms Execution time: ~38.518 ms

Subqueries from answer:

> Planning time: ~1.017 ms Execution time: ~41.288 ms

I thought that `inner_lateral_join` would be faster but it isn't. Does anybody know how to speed up this query?

Comment: Do you have a simpler query as a starting point? For example, I can't find where `osm` is coming from.

Comment: I've corrected my sql query, actually I know how to write `fragment` with `ST_Intersects`, but not subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I would try. I haven't verified it works but it should point to the proper direction:

```
segments =
  from s in Segment,
    where: fragment("ST_Intersects(?, ST_SetSrid(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1866349.262143 6886808.978425)', -1), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1883318.282423 6876413.542579)', -1)), 3857)))", s.geom),
    distinct: true,
    select: %{rel: fragment("unnest(?)", s.rel)}

hierarchy =
  from h in Hierarchy,
    join: s in subquery(segments),
    where: h.child == s.rel,
    distinct: true,
    select: %{parent: h.parent}

routes =
  from r in Route,
    join: h in subquery(hierarchy),
    where: r.top and r.id == h.parent
```

Things to keep in mind:

1. Start from the inner query and go to the outer one
2. To access the result of a subquery, you need to select a map in the subquery
3. Ecto only allows subqueries in from and join. The good news is that you can usually rewrite "x IN subquery" as a join
4. You can try to run each query individually and see if they work